# Does Tkinter work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have installed Python 3.2 from: http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter.

Step 3 - does Tkinter work?

Try the following command at the Python prompt:

> > > Tkinter._test() # note underscore in _test. Also, if you are using Python 3.1, try tkinter._test() instead. 
> > >       This should pop up a small window with two buttons.

```
>>> Tkinter._test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    Tkinter._test
NameError: name 'Tkinter' is not defined

>>> tkinter._test
<function _test at 0x00000000028FD2C8>
```

However, no 'window with 2 buttons'.
Ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run `tkinter._test()`. Note the parenthesis.

Comment: Oops! How embarrassment! Pity they can't fix the wordwrap so that the () are on the same line as the function.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
tkinter._test()
```

Note the parentheses - they are imperative when calling a function. It is if you are calling a function with arguments.

To test if a module has imported correctly (this works for any module) try:

```
import [module name here]
print([module name here])
```

An example would be:

```
import tkinter
print(tkinter)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code, you forgot to include the parentheses after test. Test is, indeed, a function so it needs parentheses:

```
tkinter._test()
```